# EF Core Query multiple tables with condition between

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have 2 tables with the following structure:

**User**

```
UserId   |   Age
----------------
     1       15
     2       36
     3       25
```

**DictAges**

```
Title   |   FromAge   |   ToAge
-------------------------------
     1        0             20
     2        20            35
     3        35            100
```

I created the neccessary models for the DbContext, called `UserModel` and `DictAgesModel` with the exact same properties shown at the table structure. I would like to query a user with its id, and join title based on the user's age. Here's the MySQL code I used before:

```
SELECT User.UserId, DictAges.Title 
FROM User, DictAges 
WHERE User.UserId = :id 
  AND User.Age BETWEEN DictAges.FromAge AND DictAges.ToAge
```

Note, that I don't have any navigation property added to any of those models (should I add any??)

How could I translate a query like this to entity framework core query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hence you don't have navigational properties,you can do as shown below.

**Query Based :**

```
from p in ctx.User  
join q in ctx.DictAges on p.UserId equals q.Title
where p.UserId == :id AND p.Age BETWEEN q.FromAge AND q.ToAge
select new {UserId = p.UserId, Title = q.Title };
```

**Method Based :**

```
ctx.User.Join(ctx.DictAges, 
     p => p.UserId,
     q => q.Title, 
     (p, q) => new { User = p, DictAges = q })
.Where(s => s.User.UserId == :id && (s.DictAges.FromAge <= s.User.Age  && s.User.Age <=  s.DictAges.ToAge) )
.Select(ss => new { UserId = ss.User.UserId, Title = ss.DictAges.Title});
```

**Note :** Hence you don't have Navigation properties,method based syntax is very complex.In other words there are a readability issues. B'cos of that I would like Query based syntax on these situations.

**Update :**

You can learn about Navigational properties using this article : [**Relationships**](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html?highlight=navigational)

Comment: could you write a lamdba version of it if I dont ask too much?

Comment: Looks nice, I'll try it soon. Until then, could you please add some more info about navigation properties, I mean which class should have it and how would that affect the query itself? Thank you anyways, if the given code works for my solution I'll accept your answer anyway.

Comment: I have updated the post.please follow the mentioned article. It explains everything about the navigational properties on EF core.

Comment: It's strange that this is accepted, since none of the two queries provided will produce the same result as the original SQL (the first one does not even compile). And navigation properties cannot be used to create range correlation.

Comment: Accepted solutions are not always perfectly compiling and working.But the most important thing is the direction which the solution shows to the OP.If that direction is correct then OP can adjust it according to his application. @IvanStoev

Comment: I doubt because none of the directions are correct - neither `join` nor navigation property. In fact they are misleading. The real solution has almost nothing in common with the answer.